# Moodle Web Service responses with invalid_parameter_exception

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I created moodle and mariadb containers with Docker.

Moodle: 3.11.4

Mariadb: 10.3

I am trying following webservice to execute:

**client:**

wwwroot: 'http://localhost:8012',

service: 'moodle_mobile_app',

token: '8faf4879d2c654f11e404095032ae382',

strictSSL: true

**call:**
curl "http://localhost:8012/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=8faf4879d2c654f11e404095032ae382&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&id=2"

but getting follwing error:
**{"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter",
"message":"Invalid parameter value detected (Missing required key in single structure:field)",
"debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: field"
}**

I tried it same with moodle client for node

`... client.call({ wsfunction: "core_user_get_users_by_field", method: "POST", args: { id: 2 } })...`
but also receiving same error.
I checked API documentation and id is valid parameter for this
webservice.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is resolved**

```
client.call({
    method: "POST",
    wsfunction: "core_user_get_users_by_field",
    args: {
        field: "id",
        values: ["2"]
    }
}).then(function(info) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(info, null, 4); 
    console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).